# C pointer problem - Address of local variable may escape the function

Tags: c, pointers

Here is my code:

```
int* return_to_main()
{
    int george = 32;
    int* pointer;
    pointer = &george;
    printf("george address: %p\n", (void *)&george);
    printf("george content: %d\n", *pointer);
    return pointer;
}

int main()
{
    int* test = return_to_main();
    printf("test address: %p\n", (void *)&test);
    printf("test content: %d\n", *test);
}
```

and it returns:

```
george address: 0061FEE8
george content: 32
test address: 0061FF1C
test content: 6422476
```

CLion says that "Address of local variable may escape the function". How do I fix this? And why is variable george and test's address and contents different?
Is it normal that variable george and variable test's address are different???

Comment: in `main` also print `test` with `%p`  . You seem to be getting confused between a pointer's location, and the location it points to

Comment: Thanks! I just changed to ```printf("test address: %p\n", test);``` now the addresses are the same, but the content is still different

Comment: `george` stops existing when the function it was defined in returns. That's how local variables work  . Instead you could return george by value  (meaning the caller receives a copy of the return value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > "Address of local variable may escape the function".

The reason for that is you are returning the address of local variable, you should not do that instead return by value or use dynamic memory allocation/ global variable etc.

one way to resolve your warning is below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* return_to_main()
{
    int george = 32;
    int* pointer;
    pointer = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if ( !pointer ) {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        return NULL;
     }
    *pointer = george;
    printf("george address: %p\n", (void *)&george);
    printf("pointer : %p\n", pointer);
    printf("george/pointer content: %d\n", *pointer);
    return pointer;
}

int main()
{
    int* test = return_to_main();

    if(test)
    {
        printf("test address: %p\n", (void *)test);
        printf("test content: %d\n", *test);
        free(test);
        test = NULL;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you explanation! Just want some more clarification: if I use dynamic allocation, why would I successfully return the contents & address? I thought dynamic allocation is used for unknown sizes

Comment: its not only about known sizes ,but also if you want your memory to persists as long as your program runs or until you frees it and memory can be accessed from any where through out the program by passing or returning them